# What does sess.run( LAYER ) return?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried to search around, but oddly enough, I can't find anything similar.

Let's say I have a few fully connected layers:

```
fc_1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc_input, 100)
fc_2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc_1, 10)
fc_3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc_2, 1)
```

When I run these with `sess.run(...)` I get a tensor back.

What is this tensor? Is it the weights? Gradients? Does `sess.run`return this for all types of layers we give it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully-connected layer is a math operation that transforms an input tensor into an output tensor. The output tensor contains the values returned by the layer's activation function, which operates on the sum of the weighted values in the layer's input tensor.

When you execute `sess.run(fc_3)`, TensorFlow performs the transformations for the three layers and gives you the output tensor produced by the third layer.